# Why compiler doesn't pass size of array char *arr[] in parameters?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Why compiler doesn't pass size of array char *arr[] in parameters? I wanted to get get size of array passed by parameter but I guess it doesn't work because even `char *a[]` is `char **` my question is why is it and can I make it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

template<class T, size_t len>
constexpr size_t lengthof(T(&)[len])
{
    return len;
}
void printarr(const char *a[]);

int main()
{
    const char *a[] = { "aba", "bd", "cd" };
    printarr(a);
}

void printarr(const char *a[])
{
    for(size_t i = 0, c = lengthof(a); i < c; i++) {
        printf("str = %s\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make it work by using the same trick you used in your `lengthof` function template.

```
template<size_t len>
void printarr(const char* (&a)[len])
{
    for(size_t i = 0, c = lengthof(a); i < c; i++) {
        printf("str = %s\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That has been a feature of C since the beginning and carried through into C++.

In the case of string arrays, the solution has been to add a trailing null character to mark the end.

The was probably done for the sake of efficiency when C started on ancient PDP computers.

Use strlen; or better yet std::string or std::vector.

Comment: As I've heard, the reason C uses NTBSes is that that was what PDP assembly used. I can't imagine null termination was done for the sake of efficiency, since it's... well, _less efficient_ than storing the length. On a PDP-11, it'd buy you a single byte of storage space per string, at the cost of making size lookup linear, causing substring operations to require an allocation in the general case, and making it very difficult to represent strings containing ASCII NULL.

Comment: It was probably something along those lines. The PDP-11 had  64,000BYTE addresses space. That would be expanded somewhat using memory mapping. PDP-11 programming was nothing like today's programming where applications routinely consume a GB of memory. In those days, strings were usually limited to 64K (2-byte lengths). Null termination in place of a count reduces that by half to one byte. It is sad that, given the radical change of hardware, we use development tools designed for ancient computers.

Answer (score 3):

Because this is required by the C++ standard, which inherited this behavior from C (and since C++ wants to stay compatible with C).

As function parameters, arrays are decayed into pointers.

You really want to use something like `std::vector<std::string>` instead. Learn more about standard C++ [STL containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/).

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a language what provides low level access to system resources.
Processor is not working with objects, but with memory addresses.

If you want predefined structures, use Java, C#, python, or c++ libs like stl.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the language, your array doesn't have a length; the compiler cannot read your mind and decide where the array begins and where it ends, and it cannot waste memory and processing to perform range checking.
The closest thing to an array length is the number of consecutive memory spaces that have been allocated by a single `new[]` invocation, but such information is only authoritative for the purpose of allocating and deallocating memory: the "array" you want to process in your function might be only a portion of a single allocation (for example, you might allocate memory to load a whole text file and process each line separately).